# Jekyll on Windows without installation

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Is there a way to run Jekyll on windows without installing Ruby or anything else?

It doesn't need to be perfect - I am basically looking for a simple way to preview a Jekyll and GitHub pages based blog.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. But what do you mean with "Jekyll and Github ages"? That would be this age too.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Typo fixed

Comment: Hmmm... my excuse is that it was late. I didn't even realize that was a typo and you actually meant "pages". I really thought you meant "ages". Sorry. <g>

Comment: Delphi Champ Rudy Velthius is here. Windows questions means Pascal legends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible without copying anything onto your machine, but it's possible without **installing** anything.

You can use [Portable Jekyll](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll) - it's a portable download including Ruby and anything else needed to run Jekyll.

Just [download it as a .zip file](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/archive/master.zip), unzip on your machine and [run `setpath.cmd`](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/wiki), which opens a command prompt with all environment variables set that you need to execute Jekyll.

I'm using this to build multiple Jekyll sites locally on my Windows machine.

---

By slightly tweaking `setpath.cmd`, it's also possible to create a batch file which you can just double-click to build your site.
[I submitted a pull request for that](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/pull/25) (but unfortunately it has not yet been merged yet), read the description for more information.

Comment: thx for the hint! it basically works - unfort. the project is quite outdated :(

Comment: I know. It was not when I started using it, but the author hasn‘t updated it for a long time now. But that‘s the only portable version of Jekyll that I know of.

Comment: Why is the zip file so huge, I am actually with 440 mb and still downloading. Might the [dockercontainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/jekyll/jekyll/) be less in size, although docker itself is huge.

Comment: It **is** a huge download, most of the size are the [`Git`](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/tree/master/Git) (909MB), [`ruby`](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/tree/master/ruby) (382 MB) and [`devkit`](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll/tree/master/devkit) (365 MB) directories. No idea why it's so big, but in the end it doesn't matter...you just download it once. I don't have much Docker experience, but if it's possible to get a similar "portable" experience with Docker, I'm all ears.

Comment: There is the [portable git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (40 mb) and [Ruby](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/ruby_ship).I think packaging windows knowledge is needed and then you can reduce the size. Docker offers jekyll for 180 mb. I will try it and let you know, although I try to avoid docker.